# Concatenating text from different text files into one

Tags: matlab

Suppose there are five text files. Contents of files are `textfile1 = i saw an alligator`, `textfile2 = alligator was sitting near a tree`, `textfile3 = alligator was sleeping`, `textfile4 = parrot was flying`, `textfile5 = parrot was flying`. 
I used the code below to find paths of textfiles containing word `alligator`:

```
sdirectory = 'C:\Users\anurag\Desktop\Animals\Annotations\';
textfiles = dir([sdirectory '*.eng']);
num_of_files = length(textfiles);
C = cell(num_of_files, 1);

for w = 1:length(textfiles)

    file = [sdirectory  textfiles(w).name];
    %// load string from a file
    STR = importdata(file);
    BL = cellfun(@lower, STR, 'uni',0);
    %// extract string between tags
    %// assuming you want to remove the angle brackets
    B = regexprep(BL, '<.*?>','');
    B(strcmp(B, '')) = [];

    %// split each string by delimiters and add to C    

    tmp = regexp(B, '/| ', 'split');
    C{w} = [tmp{:}];

end

where = [];

for j = 1:length(C) 

    file1 = [sdirectory  textfiles(j).name];

    if find(ismember(C{j},'alligator'))
        where = [where num2str(j) '.eng, ']; 
        disp(file1)   
    end   
end
```

Finally the variable `file1` will show the path of textfile containing word `alligator` one by one. Is there any way to concatenate the strings of textfiles containing the required word into a cell array.

Comment: Yes, just add `filenames{j} = file1;` after `disp(file1)`.

Comment: Thank you Sir. Can you tell me how to concatenate the strings once the address are stored.

Comment: There is one problem coming, when i run the code for another word `parrot`, the path of files shown is for both alligator and parrot. What to do??

Comment: Sir, I solved the problem by initializing an empty cell.